# Delete rows from table

Tags: sql, delete-row, sql-delete

I am having a table `TF` with rows `FILEID`, `WORD`, `FREQUENCY`. I am trying to delete all word rows with word `'and'` 'of' 'the' from the table.  Below is my query. It is not doing anything.

```
delete from TF
where WORD='of' AND WORD='and' AND WORD='the';
```

Comment: If `WORD` equals `'of'` it can't also equal `'and'` and `'the'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `OR` instead of `AND`

```
delete from TF
where WORD='of' OR WORD='and' OR WORD='the';
```

Comment: It is not reasonable to use many logical operators for one field when there are such things as ANY,ALL,IN.

Comment: Cause IN was invented 'To specify multiple possible values for a column' as w3schools.com states. It is not wrong, but it is bad coding style.

Answer (score 3):

```
delete from TF where word in ('of','and','the')
```